# Is it possible to use PostgresQL views on keystoneJS 6

Tags: postgresql, prisma, keystonejs

Using KeystoneJS next, is it possible to have PostgresQL Views?

This is my problem:

I have two tables: `[Aquirements]` and `[Sells]`, and want a `[Inventory]` View, I don't want to use a table for it.

I use KeystoneJS next which uses Prisma which happen to deal with PostgresQL Views...

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible* but fairly hacky at the moment.

KeystoneJS Next uses [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io) under the hood for database access and migrations. In addition to the Keystone list schema, Prisma tracks a schema of it's own – the Prisma Schema – which describes your data model. Amongst other things, the Prisma Schema is used by [Prisma Migrate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate) (one of the Prisma tools) to maintain the schema of the actual database. In Keystone, the Prisma Schema is generated automatically from your Keystone list schema so you generally don't need to be aware of it. Similarly, many of the Keystone CLI commands (like `keystone dev`) lean heavily on Prisma functionality.

Prisma does have [some limited support for views in Postgres](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/sql-views-postgres) but, when used, it prevents the use of Prisma Migrate. This in turn, breaks [the `keystone dev` command](https://next.keystonejs.com/guides/cli#dev). Fortunately, it doesn't actually stop Keystone from running – `keystone build` and `keystone start` should work fine.

If you decide to proceed, there are a view things you'll need to keep in mind:

- You can't use Prisma Migrate so will need another mechanism to rollout changes to your DB structure and keep it in sync with your Keystone lists. There are plenty of options available.
- You can't use `keystone dev`, or at least, not in its current state. Depending on how dirty you want to get your hands, this may not be a show stopper. If you take a look at the function, it's actually not that complicated and it's only [lines 40-54](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/packages-next/keystone/src/scripts/run/dev.ts#L40-L54) that cause the problem. If you copied/reimplemented this function and removed those lines you could run your Keystone in dev mode (which maintains your Prisma Schema) while preventing Prisma Migrate from trying to manage your DB.
- You're going to need to define your views twice – once in the DB view itself and again as a Keystone list. You'll need to keep these in sync. Note also that the view will need an `id` column – this is just an assumption that Keystone makes.
- In most cases, your view won't be [updatable](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-updatable-views) so GraphQL mutations that attempt to edit or create items will error. You can configure [access control](https://next.keystonejs.com/apis/access-control) on the list to exclude the mutations and see also the [common field config options](https://next.keystonejs.com/apis/fields#common-configuration). You probably want to config each field with these options: `ui: { createView: 'hidden', listView: 'read', itemView: 'read' }` – this tells the Admin UI to treat the list as read-only.

So, like I said, possible but pretty hacky right now. It's worth noting though, Keystone Next is still in preview and under very active dev. I'm confident this situation will improve over time.

Comment: Looks like Prisma's support for this can be tracked here.. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/678